# Why can't my project find "function" in namespace std?

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++

I have the following code:

```
@interface Model ()
{
    //...
    std::function<bool(CGFloat, CGFloat)> greaterThan;
    std::function<bool(CGFloat, CGFloat)> lesserThan;

    //...
}
@end
```

Everything worked fine in my original project.
I just created a new project, and dragged and dropped the files between the two, and in the new project I have the following errors for the above two lines:

> No type named 'function' in namespace 'std'

I don't know what the problem is - The files are .mm , why can't it find function in the names space std ?

Comment: Did you include the correct header?

Comment: Is the new project not setup to compile as C++11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `#include <functional>` to the top of your code.

Also remember to use -std=c++0x (or equivalent) in your compiler parameters; this will enable C++11 standard which is required for `std::function`.

Comment: it is included - I just dragged and dropped the files into a new project.

Comment: Depending on your compiler version it may be called std::tr1::function

Comment: Also remember to use -std=c++0x in your compiler parameters, because std::function is a new feature of C++11 and is off by default on all compilers I know of.  This is probably the issue

Comment: I don't know what you mean - I didn't do this in my original project. All I did was create a new project. Why should I need to do this ? I don't even know where I would do this.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're compiling but you just need to include -std=c++0x on the compiler command line to enable C++11 if you're using gcc,msvc, or intel compilers (and probably others).

Comment: I finally understood - Xcode was using "Compiler default", but in the old project it used C++11.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! I updated my answer to make it more clear also